# Why BufferedInputStream#reset() did not thrown a RuntimeException?

Tags: java, file-io, jvm, inputstream

`BufferedInputStream#mark(int)` function gets as an argument the limit of bytes that can be read, once read, the mark become invalidated.

In the OCP book **mark(int)** is described as:

> ...you can call mark(int) with a read-ahead limit value. You can then
>   read as many bytes as you want up to the limit value.

So the code below is setting limit value to 1 byte, after reading that byte, mark should be invalidated and calling .reset() function should throw a RuntimeException, yet it is not happening. Is it the JVM which is somehow overriding the argument passed to mark function?

```
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Path path = Paths.get("Java8_IOandNIO\\src\\main\\resources\\abcd.txt");

    File f = new File(path.toString());

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

    bis.mark(1);

    System.out.println((char) bis.read());
    System.out.println((char) bis.read());
    System.out.println((char) bis.read());

    bis.reset();

    System.out.println("called reset");

    System.out.println((char) bis.read());
    System.out.println((char) bis.read());
    System.out.println((char) bis.read());
  }
}
```

The code each time is printing data from the sample file:

```
A
B
C
called reset
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the documentation (original contract from [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset())) states:

> If the method mark has not been called since the stream was created, or the number of bytes read from the stream since mark was last called is larger than the argument to mark at that last call, then an IOException **might** be thrown.

(Emphasis mine)

This means that the limit is a *recommendation*. It is not mandatory that the mark will be invalidated after that number of bytes have been read.

Answer (score 0):

Because:

- the OCP you quoted doesn't say anything about throwing a `RuntimeException`;
- it doesn't say you can't necessarily read more;
- the OCP isn't a normative reference;
- the [real normative reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset()) doesn't say so either; and
- the stream is buffered, so it can support a mark of up to its internal buffer size, which is currently 8192 bytes.

Comment: @downcoter Which of these five statements is incorrect?